# Spring boot download file with InputStreamResource case when file does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, get

I have a working method to download a **file** using Spring Boot using `InputStreamResource` object.

Sometimes I have a case where the **file** to download does not exist, in this case when the file download is over I get **all java exceptions written in it**.

My question is how to proceed in this case to deny user file download, and have a response with 'file does not exist'?

I thought about throwing a exception but the user would not get the info without checking the logs

here's the code:

```
@GetMapping("/downloadfile")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@RequestParam(value = "filePath") String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            // What should I do there?
            //throw new CustomizeException("Could not find the file"); ?
        }
        MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName(this.servletContext, file);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .contentType(mediaType).contentLength(file.length()).body(resource);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a 404 (not found).

```
    if (!file.exists()) {
       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

You will not need to check logs or throws an exception because is already a talking status

Comment: the cast is necessary only because rest method returns a typed `ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>` and has no other meaning.

Comment: updated with more accurate return, removed useless cast